# REST post plugin broken from Drupal 8.4.5 to 8.5

Tags: 8

I just upgraded my Drupal installation from 8.4.5 to 8.5
Now my REST plugin is not getting any data on POST.

My client post like this:

```
POST /rgptemprest?_format=hal_json HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.1:443
Authorization: Basic ****REPLACED******
Content-Type: application/hal+json
Accept: application/hal+json
User-Agent: ESP8266
Connection: close
Content-Length: 108

{"netcard":"997800940160","DS18B20":"28ADBCE70800008C","battery":"2952","temperature":"23.375","rssi":"-33"}
```

On my drupal server I have a plugin
with this code (not complete)

```
public function post(array $data = []) 
{
    var_dump($data);
    if (!empty($data))
    {
```

....

And here I see the difference 
on 8.4.5 it show an array of the data sent:

```
array(5) {
  ["netcard"]=>
  string(12) "997800940160"
  ["DS18B20"]=>
  string(16) "28ADBCE70800008C"
  ["battery"]=>
  string(4) "2952"
  ["temperature"]=>
  string(6) "23.500"
  ["rssi"]=>
  string(3) "-33"
}
```

but on 8.5 it's empty

```
array(0) {
}
```

What has changed between 8.4.5 and 8.5? And what do I need to change?

Comment: I do not think you are doing anything wrong. When I look at the Request content the data is there. It is just not being transferred to the post() parameter for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wim Leers found the answer:

Change this:

```
public function post(array $data = [])
```

to:

```
public function post(array $data)
```

Comment: This worked for me as well.